# Scroll position of a jquerymobile collapsible set when expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, scroll, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I am using a jQueryMobile (v1.4.0) [collapsible set / accordions](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/accordions/) to display a list of elements and its content as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qjst/1/).

```
<div id="List" data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
       <h3>Lorem ipsum 1</h3>
       <p>Suspendisse neque...</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
       <h3>Lorem ipsum 2</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is with **scrolling when the content of an item is longer than the length of the screen**.

For instance in the fiddle:

- Open the first collapsible item
- Scroll to the bottom (if you do not have to scroll, resize the window so that you have to... otherwise the problem isn't visible)
- Open the second item

=> the first item is closed and the second item is opened, but the page scrolling doesn't change and you now see the end of the second item's content.

**Thus my question:** Is there a smart way to force the page to set the "header" of the second item at the top of the screen?

Thanks,
T.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once a collapsible is *expanded*, retrieve its' `.offset().top` and `$.mobile.silentScroll()` to that position.

```
$(document).on("expand", "[data-role=collapsible]", function () {
  var position = $(this).offset().top;
  $.mobile.silentScroll(position);
});
```

**Update:** For jQuery Mobile 1.4, use `collapsibleexpand` event.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/48Cnu/)** - jQM 1.0 - 1.1
>
> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Q7Hwz/)** - jQM 1.2 - 1.3
>
> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/J78nC/)** - jQM 1.4

Comment: I managed to make it work with JQM 1.3.2, but not with 1.4.0. Any idea why? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Hwz/5/

Comment: many events have been changed in 1.4, `expand` = `collapsibleexpand` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Q7Hwz/6/ @TimBourguignon