# Scroll position of a jquery mobile 1.0 collapsible set when expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, jquery-mobile-collapsible

My question is pretty much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685256/scroll-position-of-a-jquerymobile-collapsible-set-when-expanded) except that I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.0. The entire project has been written and I don't want to have to update it to 1.3.2 just to get this scroll feature to work with my collapsible set. Is there anything I can use from the answer provided in the linked question that can be adapted to 1.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading isn't required in order to have the *scroll* working. Only the way of listening to *expand* event is different.

**Bind**

```
$(".ui-collapsible").bind("expand", function () {
  /* scroll */
});
```

**Delegate**

```
$(document).delegate(".ui-collapsible", "expand", function () {
  /* scroll */
});
```

**Scroll**

```
var position = $(this).offset().top;

/* scroll with animation */
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: position
});

/* scroll without triggering scroll event */
$.mobile.silentScroll(position);
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/48Cnu/)**

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much! Makes perfect sense now. And for those reading this post, I also added an offset to the top like this:

```
var topoffset = 50;
var position = $(this).offset().top - topoffset;

/* scroll with animation */
$("html, body").animate({
scrollTop: position
});
```