# silentScroll() to specific item within collapsible set

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating a jQuery Mobile app with a glossary. Any time the user touches a term that is in the glossary I want it to open the glossary, open the collapsible with that id, and scroll to it.

```
// get all links within an element, assign click handler
var links = element.find(".glossaryLink");
links.each(function(index){
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        var regex = /\W/g;
        var searchID = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, "").toLowerCase();
        // open the glossary
        window.location = "#glossary";
        var entry = $("#" + searchID);
        // This is working fine, the correct collapsible is opening
        entry.collapsible( "option", "collapsed", false );

        // But this always returns 0...
        var pos = entry.offset().top;
        // ...meaning this does nothing
        $.mobile.silentScroll(pos);
    }
});
```

The code seems to be working OK in that I can open the correct collapsible (I'm getting the correct `<div>` within the collapsible-set) but its value of `pos` is always 0, so it doesn't scroll.

The [jQuery API for offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)  says that it doesn't support hidden elements but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685256/scroll-position-of-a-jquerymobile-collapsible-set-when-expanded) seems to suggest that auto-scrolling is possible on a collapsible.

Any help much appreciated!

## **EDIT**

As I've said in the comments below, the setTimeout() trick isn't working if the time < 500ms. Using @Omar ingenious solution of assigning a listener then immediately kicking it off works...

```
function addGlossaryClickHandlers(element){
    var links = element.find(".glossaryLink");
    links.each(function(index){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            var regex = /\W/g;
            var searchID = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, "").toLowerCase();
            window.location = "#glossary";
            var entry = $("#" + searchID);
            // assign listener then kick it off by expanding the collapsible
            entry.on("collapsibleexpand", function(){
                var pos = entry.offset().top;
                $.mobile.silentScroll(pos);
            }).collapsible("expand");
        });
    });
}
```

...but `pos` above is again returning 0. Stumped again, can anyone help? Stripped down [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drjimmie1976/THhYw/13/) although for some reason the last link in the collapsible is broken...

Comment: Try placing the logic that calculates the `offset` and calls `silentScroll` in a `setTimeout`. That will give the browser a chance to open the glossary before calculating the offset.

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. Thanks very much, that did the trick!  Do you want to post as an answer so I can accept it? Also, is there a generally accepted timeout needed to allow the content to be built? (I'm guessing this technique will be needed elsewhere in JQM!)

Comment: You dont need to use `setTimeout()` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/N46rM/ listen to `collapsibleexpand` function, on that stage, elements within are visible.

Comment: @Omar What's the benefit of both approaches? Is one better than the other?

Comment: setTimeout delay varies from platform/device to another, depending on their processing speed. When listening to an event, you run code whenever the event occurs, whether the device is fast or slow.

Comment: @Omar I may have been a bit hasty in accepting the setTimeout solution, you're right...setting the time to anything < 500ms means the scroll doesn't happen. I can see that the listener would be better, but I need to set it on the entire collapsible-set container...how would I get a handle on which collapsible had triggered the event listener?

Comment: @Omar would I instead attach an event listener to **every** collapsible within the collapsible-set?

Comment: You can delegate it to all collapsibles as in my code in the link on your post. Listening to event is much better always :)

Comment: @Omar it's a great solution...but pos is still returning 0 in the edited code above, using your trick of assigning a listener then immediately kicking it off. Can you help? Sorry for the question spam!

Comment: Dont worry, we will fix it. Can you setup a dummy fiddle?

Comment: @Omar Thanks, really appreciate it. Link to fiddle added above, took me ages to get it to work!

Comment: Nice work, I like it. I'll check it tomorrow, hopefully, come out with a solution :)

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. Sorry I've had to reopen the question as the timeout technique didn't work...it needed to be > 500ms, anything less and the old behaviour resurfaced.

Comment: I hope this is what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/tXg7x/ you had some mistakes: 1) duplicate ID `glossary` collapsible and collapsible-set 2) enhance collapsible set using `.collapsibleset()`.

Comment: @Omar really sorry, been working nights. Thanks for the code, it works perfectly in the fiddle but for some odd reason still getting pos of 0 in the app code. The fiddle HTML was simplified and I need to check it out and see why the behavior is different. Puzzling but I know the solution works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Omar do you want to post as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Make sure you're using unique IDs, if you want, I can review your code if you upload it to Dropbox. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to move the logic that calculates `offset` and `silentScroll` to a `setTimeout`.

As for your comment: Typically, `setTimeout(func, 0)` is the norm. However, HTML5 spec states 4ms, so you'll see some code samples where `setTimeout(func, 4)` is used.

If you're interested why this works, here's a great break down into what's happening and why setTimeout addresses the issue (it's all due to events):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575011/1253479

Thanks!